# How to read and search multiple Excel files from the given path?

Tags: c#

I am new to c#, i would like to know one requirement regarding reading multiple excel files from the given path. Just in the UI i will provide a text box for entering the path so that the code can be written in such a way that it will read all .xlsx files from the path.

Extended to this requirement i will provide another text box for entering the search item, so that the code can search all work books and if the search item matches to the any cell content it has to show the work sheet names corresponding to that work book.

Answer (score 2):

look into using the [Office interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

You could also use the OpenFileDialog and filter on xls files.

```
OpenFileDialog getFile = new OpenFileDialog();
getFile.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xslx)|*.xlsx|Csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
```